# Programatically convert string to image

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

So I've mistakenly updated all of the database contents to a single image file (junior mistakes, luckily there's a backup). I'm now trying to update the f'd-up database using the restored database's image column. However upon pulling, it gets saved as a `string` rather than its original `image` type. Is there a way to convert it back to `image`?

```
$main = DB::connection('restoredDB')
        ->table('Returns')
        ->select('signature', 'returnID')
        ->orderBy('lastUpdate', 'desc')
        ->chunk(300, function($items) {
            foreach($items as $item)
            {
               dd(gettype($item->signature)); //stopped here to determine data type
                DB::connection('destroyed_db')
                    ->table('Returns')
                    ->where('returnID', $item->returnID)
                    ->update([
                        'signature' => $item->signature
                    ]);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Why are you trying to restore it in Laravel, restore the table to a copy and write a simple query in SQL to get the column from the copy

Comment: @RiggsFolly there's already new sets of data processed and this is probably the safest option where I don't truncate the table, or further destroy the table

Comment: From personal experiences of making mistakes, it's better to own up to it, roll back to your backup and deal with the few "newer" records after. Surely it's better to restore potentially thousands, if not millions of records, than try save a select few? The longer you leave the problem, the worse it gets. Just roll it back, don't use PHP to try and fix a database problem. Your question is a bit vague too, because we don't know how your images are being saved and what format they are in SQL. Is the string a valid encoded image format like base64, or is it a path to an image on the server/CDN?